# Passing MailItem to Function

Tags: vba, outlook

I am searching how to pass a MailItem through Function.

For example: I want to call a function that extract Subject of MailItem.

```
Function testpassing(myMail As Outlook.MailItem) As Actions
    MsgBox (myMail.Subject)
End Function

Sub passing()
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myItem = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1)

    MsgBox (myItem.Subject) '<~ Work correctly
    testpassing (Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1))   '<~ Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method
    testpassing (myItem)      '<~ Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method
End Sub
```

Im new to VBA outlook. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Please show the code where you call `testpassing`

Comment: Also your `Function` doesn't actually return anything - that might also be part of the problem.

Comment: I define myItem as: Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem / Set myItem = myNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1)

Comment: When you get the runtime error, are you certain the error is on the `MsgBox( myMail.Subject )` line?

Comment: The function is called as Actions so that I think it might return none.

Comment: The error is on `testpassing (myItem)` line

Comment: Is `testpassing` defined in the same Macro Module?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: One more thing is: if I declare testpassing function without declare myMail, it implicity declare myMail as something then it work? `Function testpassing(myMail) As Actions`

Comment: I suggest you post your entire macro module here, there's too much context missing to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The entire macro is too messy but I will shorten it then post here.

Comment: Call it `testpassing myItem` And `testpassing Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items(1)`

Comment: @0m3r WOW! You're legend!

Comment: also look into ByRef and ByVal - see link on my asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it `testpassing myItem` And `testpassing Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderIn‌​box).Items(1)`

also look into ***[ByRef and ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx)***

You can pass arguments to a procedure (function or sub) by reference or by value.

As always Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

The folder may contain different item types. I'd suggest checking the item type first (or message class):

```
 If Item(1).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then 
    '
 End If
```

See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for more information.